# Keep app rolling on sleep mode

Tags: wear-os

My app needs to keep receiving data from BLE devices when the user hits the side button and "kill" the app or it simply run in sleep mode. How can I save the state of my app and his listeners so I can keep receiving the data?

I've read some approaches but I want to know what is the one more indicate.

- Launch a service as the center of my app?
- Launch pendingIntent so the user can re-enter the app after sleep mode? In this case how can I keep my listeners for receiving data?(service?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I've implemented was the first one!

I've completely detached the center of my app from the UI activity and implemented a service as the "brain". The service and the activity are in constant communication through a broadcast channel. When the smartwatch is in sleep mode I launch a pendindIntent (card) so the system can recover to the main activity.

That's how I've done it, hope it helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

Your app can implement a WearableListenerService; framework will instantiate it when you have a message/data and calls its appropriate callbacks with the message or data that has arrived.